# TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable in Python

Tags: json, dictionary, tkinter, response, callable

This method I am Calling Weather API with key and the parameter in the form of dictinoary, but its throwing error in line:

```
response = request.GET(url, params=params)
```

> TypeError: 'dict' object is not Callable

```
def get_weather():
print('this is the weather')
user = entry.get()
key = '6557bbd7dbca062ddf4fe0XXXXXX'
# api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name},{country code}
url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
params = {'APPID':key, 'q': user, 'units':'metric'}
response = request.GET(url, params=params)
#print(response.JSON())  this also didn't worked
return jsonify(response.JSON())
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: response = request.GET(url, params=params)

I was using request, and had imported request lib, where I should be using requests lib and from which requests.get(url, params=params).

I corrected it and got the desired output.
Thanks